# [ByteTrack]Tuple indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Tags: python, object-detection, yolov5, tracker, object-tracking

I can't figure out how to pass detections to ByteTrack (https://github.com/ifzhang/ByteTrack)
I tried to follow the instructions given by the creator but nothing went as planned.
Here is my code:

```
    # Perform object detection with YOLOv5
    results = model(frame)
    #print(results)
    
    # Process detection results
    bbs = []
    for det in results.pandas().xyxy[0].iterrows():
        _, detection = det
        xmin = float(detection.xmin) 
        ymin = float(detection.ymin) 
        xmax = float(detection.xmax - xmin) 
        ymax = float(detection.ymax - ymin) 
        confidence = float(detection.confidence)
        class_id = int(detection.name)
        
        if class_id >= 0 and class_id < len(class_labels):
                class_label = class_labels[class_id]
        if confidence > conf_threshold: # 0.4
            # Append detection to the list of bounding boxes
            bbs.append((xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax, confidence, class_id)) 
            #print(bbs)
            
    dets = (bbs, num_classes)
    #print(dets)
    
    # Pass detection results to BYTETracker
    online_targets = tracker.update(dets, img_size) #, info_imgs
```

And the error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[17], line 77
     73 dets = (bbs, num_classes)
     74 #print(dets)
     75 
     76 # Pass detection results to BYTETracker
---> 77 online_targets = tracker.update(dets, img_size) #, info_imgs
     79 # Process tracking results
     80 for target in online_targets:

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\bytetrackpypi\lib\site-packages\bytetracker\byte_tracker.py:186, in BYTETracker.update(self, dets, _)
    183 lost_stracks = []
    184 removed_stracks = []
--> 186 xyxys = dets[:, 0:4]
    187 xywh = xyxy2xywh(xyxys)
    188 confs = dets[:, 4]

TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by transforming dets into float tensors:

```py
dets = torch.FloatTensor(bbs)
```